# MongoDB Performance issue after updating TTL

Tags: mongodb, ttl

We reduced TTL on a 500M elements collection and then my cpu I/O wait instantly climbed from 1 to 11% constant on all members of the replica. (Mongo 2.6 - One 3 members replica set, sas disks on raid10) 
I was hoping it will get back to normal after some hours of replication. But now It has been more than 2 weeks and it stays still. 
In the offical Documentation, there's not so much about good practices or problems related stuff to TTL.
I don't see any currentOp() on indexes. There were no replication lag the first days but when we upgraded the servers by doubling up the ram and disabling the numa configuration (as [recommended](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/administration/production-notes/)) then some lag appeared. It's increasing/decreasing depending on the app load. One node is staying pretty close <8sec but not the other (which was the former primary before the hardware upgrade), it is actually 2h30 behind the primary.

If you have any suggestions, ideas ?

Comment: To clarify, the 1 to 11% jump in I/O wait occurred after creating the TTL index? You can also reduce the frequency at which the TTL thread runs if you restart mongod with the argument "--setParameter ttlMonitorSleepSecs=<number of seconds>". By default it is 60, try increasing it and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's a good idea regarding the size of the collection, I'll try when we'll have  a maintenance timeframe. But no, we didn't create the Index, it was already there, just the ttl was reduced with a colmod cmd.